# Adding image to existing data frame using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, color, data-driven-pages, jpg

This is the first time I am using Python on my own, and I have searched for this answer for a few hours with no luck.  I am wanting to take a .JPG image and put it in a data frame.  The image has to be in color, and needs to change with data driven pages.

Comment: Welcome Megan.  I assume you are aware that JPGs do not have a spatial reference (i.e. unless you are referring to .jp2).  What purpose will the JPG serve?  Will you need to georeference the JPG?

Comment: The jpg is just a picture of a station that is being located on the map.  I do not need to do anything with the picture besides add it to the correct page.

Comment: Are you sure you want to add it to a data frame as an analysis layer?  Or could you just add it to Layout page?

Comment: This is actually a nice idea - if you were generating a mapbook for a client and needed to display a picture of each asset as you moved through the DDP's. I can see this being quite useful. Almost like using a dynamic attribute except in this case it would link to a file.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest for you to template out your map document with a pseudo image and just replace the source using python instead of adding and removing the layer.  I take that your image is an element, not actually apart of a data frame.  If so, you may swap out the reference path to that image by using the

> sourceImage

property, see code example below:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\Project.mxd")
for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "PICTURE_ELEMENT"):
    if elm.name == "Photo":
        elm.sourceImage = r"C:\Project\Data\NewPhoto.bmp"
mxd.save()
del mxd
```

Otherwise, you could technically store this image in a seperate data frame and resource it by the [layer replaceDataSource](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/) method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need Python for this, unless there are other complicating factors not mentioned in the question.

Assuming that your JPG files are georeferenced (i.e. have *.jgw world files), and that you have a polygon feature class with one rectangular polygon that corresponds to each JPG file, then you should be able to use that polygon feature class as an index in Data Driven Pages.

Make sure the map you are enabling DDP on has all the JPG files in its Table of Contents and turned on.

Comment: My layout is 2 maps and image.  One map is an overall state map with a star where the approximant location of the station is and the other is zoomed in on the location of the station.  Under these two maps will be an image of the station.   I am using python to move a star where the approximant location of the station on the state map and also adding the image to the bottom.

Comment: I suspect that you may need to move away from DDP and use a map which is unenabled for that - which does need Python.  Are the disk locations of your image files available in a field on your stations feature class?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a 'dynamic image' like 'dynamic attributes' - this might be a starting point:

From [ArcGIS Pro's help: Dynamic Image](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/layouts/add-and-modify-graphics-and-text.htm)

> **Insert dynamic pictures with Map Series**
>
> If you are using Map Series, you can make your picture element dynamic
>   and have it update for each page. To do this, double-click the picture
>   to open the Element pane. There are two options from which you can
>   choose: Simple path and Dynamic (Map Series).
>
> Dynamic (Map Series) allows you to reference images that you have as
>   attachments on index layer features. You can also reference a raster
>   field as well. In cases where you have more than one attachment for a
>   feature, you should use the Name filter. For example, you can filer on
>   the file type (.png) or on a portion of text in the name.